# mysql find count of records each month and by referencing two dates

Tags: mysql

update: this can be done with python. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824617/pandas-add-the-months-between-two-dates-as-a-new-rows)

i have a table like this:

```
event_id   vendor_id    start_date     end_date
1          100          2021-01-01     2021-01-31
2          101          2021-01-15     2021-02-15
3          102          2021-02-01     2021-02-31
4          103          2021-02-01     2021-03-31
5          104          2021-03-01     2021-03-31
6          105          2021-03-01     2021-04-31
7          100          2021-04-01     2021-04-31
```

i would like an output like this: number of events based on month. but if the event between two or more months, it must be included in the count for each month. For example, The event in the second row (event_id=2) takes place in both January and February. Therefore, this event should be included in the total both in January and February.

output:

```
month    total_event
2021-01  2        ---->> event_id=(1,2)
2021-02  3        ---->> event_id=(2,3,4)
2021-03  3        ---->> event_id=(4,5,6)
2021-04  2        ---->> event_id=(6,7)
```

Note: I wrote it to make the "  --->> event_id= :  " part better understood. i dont needed. i just need the month and the total_event.
i tried this query:

```
select date_format(start_date,'%Y-%m') as month,count(event_id) as total_event
group by date_format(start_date,'%Y-%m')

month    total_event
2021-01  2
2021-02  2
2021-03  2
2021-04  1
```

but it counts only by start_date, so the numbers are missing.

Comment: Look up `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` and maybe `MONTH()` Have some sort of stab at creating a query. Then if it does nto work quite right, then ask a question here

Comment: I can only count the events in a single month with success, but I could not include the events covering more than one month into the total. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 2 month between start and end date?

Comment: @Alaindeseine. yes. There is a maximum difference of 5 months now. however, this difference may increase in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

1. To get the valid months list from the table
2. To calculate the event counts by event table's joining with the months

**MySQL 8.0+**

We can get the valid months list by `Recursive`.

Here is a full SQL. Assumed that your event table is `c`!

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_dates(dt) AS (
    -- anchor
    SELECT MIN(c.`start_date`) AS dt FROM c
    UNION ALL
    -- recursion with stop condition
    SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
    FROM all_dates WHERE dt + INTERVAL 1 MONTH <= (SELECT MAX(c.end_date) FROM c)
)
SELECT LEFT(dt, 7) AS `month`, COUNT(d.dt) AS total_event, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.`event_id`) AS event_ids FROM all_dates d
INNER JOIN c ON LEFT(d.dt, 7) >= LEFT(c.start_date, 7) AND LEFT(d.dt, 7) <= LEFT(c.end_date, 7)
GROUP BY LEFT(dt, 7);
```